# How to concatenate / append a string to another one in Jekyll / Liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

To be clear, assuming:

```
{% assign my_var = "123" %}
{% assign another_var = "456" %}
```

I would like to append string to `my_var` to get something like `123 - 456`

What I have tried so far:

```
{% assign my_var = my_var + " - " + another_var %}
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You could use the `capture` logic tag:

```
{% capture new_var %}{{ my_var }} - {{ another_var }}{% endcapture %}
```

It is also possible to use the `append` filter, as Ciro pointed:

```
{% assign new_var = my_var | append: ' - ' | append: another_var %}
```

Comment: This is great. An important thing to stress about this answer is not to break the capture onto multiple lines as it's whitespace sensitive. If I tried to make my template more readable by doing so, I found my comparison would return false because it captures the line breaks as well.

Comment: If you do want to break the capture onto multiple lines, then you can use `{%-` and `-%}` to strip out white spaces. https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/

Answer (score 57):

**`append:` filter**

This is more convenient than `capture` for short concatenations:

```
{% assign x = 'abc' %}
{% assign y = 'def' %}
{% assign z = x | append: ' - ' | append: y %}
{{ z }}
```

Output:

```
abc - def
```

Tested on jekyll 3.0.4 (github-pages 75).

Answer (score 9):

All the answers so far are correct, but they fail to mention that you can also inline the append instead of having to assign a new variable:

```
<a href="{{ foo | append: ' - ' | append: bar }}">Link</a>
```